# Python: program to get the real name of decorated function

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I want to write a decorator to show the really name of the decorated functions, but something goes wrong when I write in this way.

```
from functools import update_wrapper

def decorator(d):
    def _decorator(f):
        update_wrapper(d(f), f)
        return d(f)
    return _decorator

@decorator
def add2(f):
    def _add2(x,y):
        return f(x,y)*2
    return _add2

@add2
def add(x,y): return x+y
```

If I want to get the name of add(x,y), it shows like this:

```
>>>print add.__name__
_add2
```

But if I make little change to func decorator like this:

```
def decorator(d):
    def _decorator(f):
        return update_wrapper(d(f), f)
    return _decorator
```

The result will be correct:

```
>>>print add.__name__
add
```

I'm really confused about that. In my mind, that shouldn't make such difference because they are almost the same.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question. Is "Why does functools.update_wrapper keep my function name unchanged, whilst my homebrew decorator doesn't?" an accurate rephrasing?

Comment: Use `wraps` https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps

Comment: @KlausD.: `update_wrapper()` is the underlying implementation for `wraps`..

Comment: @ymbirtt: update_wrapper() are used in two version of 'def decorator(d)', but they are wrote in different way, but in the later vesrion, It seems useless in keeping my function name unchanged. That's exactly what I want to know

Comment: Sorry, that's not really clarified anything to me. What are you trying to achieve here? What did you try? Why did you do that? What happened? What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `d(f)` **twice**, and each creates a new wrapper function object; these are independent, new copies. You only a apply `update_wrapper()` to the first result and return the second.

Call it *once*:

```
def decorator(d):
    def _decorator(f):
        wrapper = d(f)
        update_wrapper(wrapper, f)
        return wrapper
    return _decorator
```